# Got Reversed Image from Byte Array when converting to Base64

Tags: c#, image, arrays, reverse

I need to get the raw bitmap data only (no header, or other information). I used the following code to get the bitmap data:

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = svgDocument.Draw())
{
  Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
  BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);
  var length = Math.Abs(bitmapData.Stride) * bitmapData.Height;

  byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
  Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, bytes, 0, length);
  bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

  MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
  string filename = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".bmp"; // this works fine
  bitmap.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Bmp);

  string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks); // the base64 is reversed. 
}
```

When I save the bitmap, everything looks fine. The image is not reversed. However when I use the bytes only to convert the data to Base64, then the image is reversed.

**Edit 1:**

I think this has nothing to do with the Base64 conversion. It seems that the bytes are in reversed order.

When I save the image using the code, the image looks like this:

[image]

When I use the bytes, then I see this:

[image]

**Solution:**

I found the solution. Instead of creating a new bitmap, I just skipped the first 54 bytes of header information and then stored the byte array.

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);

// Skip header
IEnumerable<byte> bytes = memoryStream.ToArray().Skip(54);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reversed"? Can you give an example of the content of `bytes` and the resulting `base64`? Are you sure it's not just an issue with the way you save the `bmp` file in your second situation?

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by "with the code" and "with the bytes"? What is the code you use in both cases?

Comment: "With the code", I mean the code used above. "With the bytes", I mean by just using the bytes as created above as well. I use the bytes to generate the base64 string, which can be parsed by any online base64 tested to see the result. In my case though I need to save the base64 into an xml file, which is then read by a third party. It seems that the bytes order is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Instead of creating a new bitmap, I just skipped the first 54 bytes of header information and then stored the byte array.

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);

// Skip header
IEnumerable<byte> bytes = memoryStream.ToArray().Skip(54);
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard BMP format allows to store bytes of the image either in classical top/down order or in reverse order.

The way to tell whether your image is stored this way is to check the value of the `Height` parameter in the BMP header:

- If `Height < 0`, then the height of your image is `abs(Height)` and the pixels are stored in reverse (bottom / top) order.
- If `Height > 0`, then you are in the case you expect, where pixels are in 'normal' order, top to bottom.

I would say that what happens in your case is that you are starting from an image stored with a negative `Height` header (the `SVG` object must do that for some reason). But you do not check it, so you store the pixels in bottom to top order.

When you store with the `BMP` object, it figures that out for you from the context. But when you export just the pixels, then the third party application that loads your image sees positive `Height` and thus shows your image upside down.

You can find details about this pixel ordering in the [Wikipedia page for BMP file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).

**Edit:**

So, when you write a BMP file to your disk, you have to do the following:

1. Check whether your bytes are in top to bottom order (a) or in bottom to top order (b)
2. If (a): put the `height` of your image as a positive value in the BMP header
3. If (b): put `- height` as a negative value in the BMP header. So that the third party program that shows your image knows that it's reversed.

Comment: What can I do if the bmp is stored in a reverse order? Can I put it back into the correct order?

Comment: I checked the bitmap.Height and its > 0.

Comment: You just have to write the final BMP with the `height` that matches the order of the bytes you write.

Comment: So you don't have to reverse the bytes yourself, just make sure that `height` is `> 0` or `< 0` as you need.

Comment: Sorry I can't, I don't have sample code but I edited my answer.

Comment: But the written bmp file appears fine when I save it. Its the "bytes" that are wrong. Also I cant have the header in the 3rd party application, only the bitmap data is needed.

Comment: I don't know the specificities of your situation, but bottom line is: the order of the bytes you write in the file are not the one that is announced by the BMP header. So you have to fix that, whatever way you use to write everything. Just make the order of the bytes the same as the sign of `header.height`. That's it. Then figure out the specificities depending on your implementation. If you don't write the header yourself, some library/function does it otherwise it would be an invalid BMP file. So find out where, and give the right sign for Height.

Comment: If that doesn't help, open your file in hexa and see exactly what happens, and if my answer makes sense. It is obviously just a logical problem as the image is not screwed up or anything: it is just wrongly interpreted.

Comment: Mic, I found the solution. Instead of creating a new bitmap, I just skipped the header information and stored the remaining bytes into a new array.

Comment: nice, please mark as an answer or post your answer to close the topic then. Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem but still needed a base 64 string (for HTML5 canvas). So I used the Image class to rotate the image, stored in a new stream, then convert to base64 string.

```
var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bytes));

//Rotate and save to new stream
image.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
MemoryStream streamOut = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(streamOut, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

//Convert to base64 string
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(streamOut.ToArray());
```